# Can stored procedures return a result set?

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I have a table named employee, which has his id, name, phone number. I am using MySQL as my database. I am using Java Swing for that. I am searching the employee table with name now using Java (I have used `like` clause in my Java page).

Now I need to implement that function in stored procedures. Is it possible? And how can we take that resultset in Java code, if it is possible??

Now I have written my stored procedure as follows

```
BEGIN
     SELECT * FROM employee where empName like '%su%'
END
```

Sample code will be appreciated..
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First thing is you should write msql procedure that sends parameter for `LIKE`,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE simpleproc (param1 CHAR(20))
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM employee where empName like param1;
END
```

Then from java program you can use this code to use procedure,

```
CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall("{call simpleproc(?)}");
cstmt.setString(1, "%su%");
ResultSet rs = cstmt.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

When executing a stored procedure it may actually return multiple ResultSet objects and/or update counts if it does several statements.

You use `CallableStatement` to execute the proc and then `getResultSet()` or `getUpdateCount()` to get the right result. For multiple results sets/statements you call `getMoreResults()` to move through the results of the stored proc.

For a simple case like this you should just need to call `getResultSet()` once and process it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. A stored procedure can even return multiple resultsets.

```sql
DELIMITER $$ -- recognized by mysql client but not phpmyadmin

CREATE PROCEDURE prc_test()
BEGIN
        SELECT  *
        FROM    employee
        WHERE   empName LIKE '%su%';
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;

CALL prc_test(); -- to call
```